Laravel Octane Swoole exit() triggered when using with 24Slides/laravel-saml2 package for SSO
I'm having problem when using this package with Laravel 11 Octane running Swoole. As my debug, the problem occur when WSO2 IS authenticated and request to my /saml2/{uuid}/acs route (i use the default route generated by this package).
I recieved swoole exit. Is there any way to resolve this problem?

Laravel: 11
Octane: swoole
PHP: 8.2
WSO2 IS: 7.0.0

error page:

Below is what has been logged in laravel.log
[2024-10-30 22:36:55] local.DEBUG: [Saml2] Tenant resolved {"uuid":"07bb3477-fc64-49e3-851d-b9aac6c6bb20","id":4,"key":"identity-provider"}

[2024-10-30 22:36:55] local.ERROR: swoole exit {"exception":"[object] (Swoole\ExitException(code: 0): swoole exit at /var/www/vendor/onelogin/php-saml/src/Saml2/Utils.php:377)

I tried to use middlware for saml to redirect without header() and exit() but not any better than.
